# Get all items in DynamoDB with API Gateway's Mapping Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, velocity

Is there a simple way to retrieve all items from a DynamoDB table using a mapping template in an API Gateway endpoint? I usually use a lambda to process the data before returning it but this is such a simple task that a Lambda seems like an overkill.

I have a table that contains data with the following format:

```
roleAttributeName    roleHierarchyLevel    roleIsActive    roleName
"admin"                99                    true            "Admin"
"director"             90                    true            "Director"
"areaManager"          80                    false           "Area Manager"
```

I'm happy with getting the data, doesn't matter the representation as I can later transform it further down in my code.

I've been looking around but all tutorials explain how to get specific bits of data through queries and params like `roles/{roleAttributeName}` but I just want to hit `roles/` and get all items.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is

1. create a resource (without curly braces since we dont need a particular item)
2. create a get method
   use Scan instead of Query in Action while configuring the integration request.

Configurations as follows :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzkRv.png)

3. now try test...you should get the response.
4. to try it out on postman deploy the api first and then use the provided link into postman followed by your resource name.

Comment: Shouldn't we use a mapping for this? I'm getting this error for the above answer: com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway allows you to Proxy DynamoDB as a service. [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/) you have an interesting tutorial on how to do it (you can ignore the part related to index to make it work).

To retrieve all the items from a table, you can use *Scan* as the action in API Gateway. Keep in mind that DynamoDB [limits the query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-api) sizes to 1MB either for *Scan* and *Query* actions.
You can also limit your own query before it is automatically done by using the *Limit* parameter.

[AWS DynamoDB Scan Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)